# How can I use hover and click depending on different devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hover

I have a menu button which is half visible and half outside the screen. The full button is visible only when it is **'hovered'** (I've written **CSS** for this, the button moves horizontal so it is displayed fully). Now this works on Desktop website. But as you know hover is not available on Mobile sites, so hover is converted to click. The click makes the button fully visible but it does not hide again when clicked again, because we have not defined click event to display and hide it, because it won't interfere with hover.

So is there any short and efficient way to do this, so that hover works on desktop and click works on phone for the same (display and hide) function?

You can use CSS or jQuery or both.

Comment: Can you please show your code.

Comment: Are the URL's different for desktop and mobile? For instance: mywebsite.com and m.mywebsite.com. You could execute different code depending on the url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case, I suggest you set a `hover function` within a break-point that suits desktops and a `click function` within a break-point that suits mobile device. See my example below and adjust as needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

// When document is ready check window width, then choose hover/click
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
      $("div").hover(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("increase");

    });

  } else {

    $("div").click(function() {
      $(this).toggleClass("increase");

    });
  }
});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 15px;
  line-height: 45px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: all 1s;
}

div.increase {
  width: 150px;
  height: 45px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div> I am the Button</div>
```

Note: in my example; `hover` toggles the height/width when device width is wider than 768px, while a `click` toggles the height/width when device width is less than 768px

Answer (score 0):

its simple try this

1 - disable hover on mobile device using media query

@media screen and (max-width:767px){

button:hover{ just disable css u r using  }
}

2- add this jquery - this code adding and removing a class on the button click

$('button').click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass('btnClick');

});

3: now write the same hover css for this class

.btnClick{

}